# How can I disable the keyboard shortcuts in the Stack Overflow editor?

Tags: support, feature-request, keyboard-shortcuts

I am using Chrome on a MacBook. I am used to the Emacs keyboard shortcuts available almost everywhere in the window manager, shell prompt and browser, such as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> for cursor movement and simple editing.

The Stack Overflow editor redefines some of these by default: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> for bold, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> for code, etc. while not the others. How can I disable such a redefinition?

There is a user profile option to enable keyboard shortcuts, but it does not apply to these.

Comment: On MSE: [Is there a way to disable the hotkeys?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/2980) [meta-tag:status-ignored]

Comment: Related on MSE: [On Mac browsers, ⌘-L should select the address bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100349), (suggesting further evil) [Keyboard shortcut for formatting posts on mac should support ⌘](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78599) and (strangely deleted) http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/38097/, http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44097/

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I was wondering how to ask you in person this question. SO designers do not seem keen on helping those of us who have acquired medullar reflexes. Do you have a fix or are you still annoyed many times a day?

Comment: I installed RobW's script documented in this answer: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/123256/285279 but it almost never works.

Comment: @chqrlie: This still drives me crazy, yes. :) At this point I've resorted to copy-pasting the post text that I want to write/edit into TextMate or Emacs! I also tried that script, or something very similar, and likewise had inconsistent results.

Comment: @JoshCaswell: I have a solution! I modified RobW's script along an idea by Rod Neyrehm: http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/23-Reclaim-Your-Keyboard-Shortcuts-in-Firefox.html .  The idea is to prevent any element from grabbing certain keys.  I will post an answer.

Comment: Try being a German Java, Ruby, or Perl developer. `@` on a German keyboard is Ctrl+Alt+q which the StackOverflow editor interprets as Ctrl+q, or blockquote. It is simply impossible to type an `@` sign into the SO editor with a German keyboard layout. My "fix"? Spend 1500€ on a Mac, where the `@` sign lives on a different key. (Well, I admit, that wasn't the reason I bought it, but it was a nice side-effect.)

Comment: This is StackOverflow's biggest UI problem.  It hits me literally every time I ask or answer a question, and those two activities are supposedly what this site is all about.  I can't believe it has gone unanswered for so long.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I had installed RobW's script to disable the hotkeys in the SO editor, but it does not work anymore.  Here is a different script that disables specific keys for all elements in the document. I have put the 4 emacs bindings that are overridden by the SO editor (WMD), but other shortcuts should be added for MacOS users with muscle memory.

I got the idea from http://blog.rodneyrehm.de/archives/23-Reclaim-Your-Keyboard-Shortcuts-in-Firefox.html

### Install as a User Script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           OSX shortcut disabler 
// @namespace      chqrlie
// @version        1.0
// @match          https://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          https://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          https://superuser.com/*
// @match          https://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match          https://serverfault.com/*
// @match          https://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match          https://askubuntu.com/*
// @match          https://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match          https://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match          https://mathoverflow.net/*
// @match          https://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match          https://stackapps.com/*
// @run-at         document-end
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

(typeof unsafeWindow !== 'undefined' ? unsafeWindow : window).$(function() {
    document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
        // Prevent propagation of emacs key bindings
        if (e.ctrlKey) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
              case 0x42: // ^B  backward-char
              case 0x49: // ^I  indent-line
              case 0x4B: // ^K  kill-line
              case 0x59: // ^Y  yank
                e.stopImmediatePropagation();
                return;
            }
        }
    }, true);
});
```

### Install as a Chrome extension:

1. Create a directory, and store the following two files in it.
2. Visit chrome://extensions/
3. Enable Developer mode
4. Click on the button <kbd>Load unpacked extension...</kbd>.
5. Select the directory from step 1.

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Chqrlie shortcut disabler",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["contentscript.js"],
        "matches": [
            "https://stackoverflow.com/*",
            "https://*.stackoverflow.com/*",
            "https://superuser.com/*",
            "https://meta.superuser.com/*",
            "https://serverfault.com/*",
            "https://meta.serverfault.com/*",
            "https://askubuntu.com/*",
            "https://meta.askubuntu.com/*",
            "https://*.stackexchange.com/*",
            "https://mathoverflow.net/*",
            "https://*.mathoverflow.net/*",
            "https://stackapps.com/*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

**contentscript.js**

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    // Prevent propagation of emacs key bindings
    if (e.ctrlKey) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 0x42: // ^B  backward-char
          case 0x49: // ^I  indent-line
          case 0x4B: // ^K  kill-line
          case 0x59: // ^Y  yank
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return;
        }
    }
}, true);
```

Comment: Nice. You should post this on http://stackapps.com ;)

Comment: @404: Thanks, updated. Is there an official list?  Is there a way to coalesce `domain.com` and `*.domain.com`?

Comment: This doesn't work on Mac/OS X v10.11.6, Chrome v58.0.3029.110.  Still activates the text formatting shortcuts of Stack Overflow.

Comment: @user3112401 I fixed the code above by switching the match clauses to use `https:` URLs instead of `http:`.

Comment: `// @include        /^https?:\/\/(?!chat)\w*.?(stackexchange.com|stackoverflow.com|serverfault.com|superuser.com|askubuntu.com|stackapps.com|mathoverflow.net)\/.*/`

Comment: `Userscripts` (apps.apple.com/us/app/userscripts/id1463298887?mt=12) is a free extention that helped me to save the script. Could I also as a keybinding for `backward kill a word`? @chqrlie

Comment: Can I apply the exact code on other editors such as hackerrank's code editor bottom of the page (https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/py-hello-world/problem)?

Answer (score 0):

Install my [open source](https://github.com/verhovsky/disable-stackexchange-editor-shortcuts) Chrome extension: [No Stack Exchange Editor Keyboard Shortcuts](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/no-stackexchange-editor-k/nhdklhaffdlobbdgheaehofbnfebeddm).