# Command-G (find next) is broken in editing area

Tags: bug

On OS X, when writing a post in Safari, your website is overriding the standard keystroke Command-G (Find Next) and using it to pops up some photo posting overlay.  This is extremely nonstandard and violates the Apple HIG pretty badly.

Please stop doing that.  Websites should not override command-key behavior to make those shortcuts do something different.  And they absolutely should not do so for a command-key combo that people use all the time when editing (Command-F, Command-G, Command-Shift-G, Command-C, Command-V, Command-X).

Comment: *"Websites should not override command-key behavior."* I don't know about that. Should they not bind `Cmd`+`B` or `Cmd`+`I` for the expected bold and italic shortcuts?

Comment: In my mind, that's not overriding the behavior.  That's doing exactly what it is supposed to do.  :-)  I guess I could have worded that better.  Fixed.

Comment: If they make it something different they violate my key-bindings ...

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Closely related: [On Mac browsers Command-L should select the address bar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/100349), [Please do not hijack Command-Q](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/47316) Related in the wrong direction: [Keyboard shortcut for formatting posts on Mac should support ⌘](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78599)

Comment: Also see: [How can I disable the keyboard shortcuts in the Stack Overflow editor?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318983)

Comment: Wow.  Folks have actually taken the time to create custom browser extensions just to work around the bad behavior of this website.  I guess I shouldn't be surprised.  I have a browser extension to forcibly inject custom CSS into Slashdot for the same reason....

Comment: Irritatingly, it also overrides Ctrl-Z, which means that Ctrl-Z undoes _twice_, once by the overriden JavaScript, and once by the browser.

Answer (score 1):

I modified the [browser extension](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/318983) to work for Macs. It might also work for PCs, but I'm not on one right now, so I can't tell.

This plugin also solves [a related problem with cutting and pasting](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/323401). Feel free to modify this to your heart's desire.

To install this in Chrome, just create a new folder and save these files to it. Then go to chrome://extensions/ and enable Developer mode. Just click Load Unpacked Extension, and select the folder!

**contentscript.js**

```
document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.metaKey||e.ctrlKey) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 70: // F  find
          case 71: // G  find-next
          case 86: // V  paste
          case 88: // X  cut
          case 90: // Z  undo
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return;
        }
    }
}, true);
```

**manifest.json**

```
{
    "name": "Stack Overflow shortcut disabler",
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "version": "1.0",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "js": ["contentscript.js"],
        "matches": [
            "http://stackoverflow.com/*",
            "http://*.stackoverflow.com/*",
            "http://superuser.com/*",
            "http://meta.superuser.com/*",
            "http://serverfault.com/*",
            "http://meta.serverfault.com/*",
            "http://askubuntu.com/*",
            "http://meta.askubuntu.com/*",
            "http://*.stackexchange.com/*",
            "http://mathoverflow.net/*",
            "http://*.mathoverflow.net/*",
            "http://stackapps.com/*"
        ]
    }]
}
```

---

OK, I'll also edit the user script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Stack Overflow shortcut disabler
// @version        1.0
// @match          http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          http://*.stackoverflow.com/*
// @match          http://superuser.com/*
// @match          http://meta.superuser.com/*
// @match          http://serverfault.com/*
// @match          http://meta.serverfault.com/*
// @match          http://askubuntu.com/*
// @match          http://meta.askubuntu.com/*
// @match          http://*.stackexchange.com/*
// @match          http://mathoverflow.net/*
// @match          http://*.mathoverflow.net/*
// @match          http://stackapps.com/*
// @run-at         document-end
// @grant          none
// ==/UserScript==

(typeof unsafeWindow !== 'undefined' ? unsafeWindow : window).$(function() {
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.metaKey||e.ctrlKey) {
        switch (e.keyCode) {
          case 70: // F  find
          case 71: // G  find-next
          case 86: // V  paste
          case 88: // X  cut
          case 90: // Z  undo
            e.stopImmediatePropagation();
            return;
        }
    }
  }, true);
});
```

Comment: @rene IDK... I've changed the user script too so maybe that would work in Safari.